# How to rename the final generated file in a Brunch plugin?

Tags: plugins, fingerprint, brunch

I'm developing a plugin for BrunchJS and i don't understand everything.

https://github.com/dlepaux/fingerprint-brunch
Inspirated by `github.com/mutewinter/digest-brunch` and `github.com/jgallen23/grunt-hash`

Concept :
Rename output filename and write it into a manifest with a key (to get the real filename).

Exemple : 
In this config file i want to make a `/js/master.js` file.

The goal of this plugin is to rename this filename like this : `master.[hash].js`

Next write this in a manifest : `{'/js/master.js' : '/js/master.[hash].js'}`

I hope you will help me to understand how do what i what to do.

```
exports.config =
  paths:
    public: './../public'
    compass: './config.rb'
    watched: ['app']

  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo: 
        '/js/master.js': /^(bower_components[\/\\]bootstrap-sass-twbs|bower_components[\/\\]bootstrap-datepicker|app)/

        #'/js/vendor/response.js': /^(bower_components[\/\\]responsejs)/
        #'/js/vendor/head.min.js': /^(bower_components[\/\\]headjs)/
        #'/js/vendor/jquery.min.js': /^(bower_components[\/\\]jquery)/
        #'/js/vendor/media.match.min.js': /^(bower_components[\/\\]media-match)/

  modules:
    wrapper: false
    definition: false

  conventions:
    # we don't want javascripts in asset folders to be copied like the one in 
    # the bootstrap assets folder
    assets: /assets[\\/](?!javascripts)/

  plugins:
    cleancss:
      keepSpecialComments: 0
      removeEmpty: true
    sass:
      debug: 'comments' # or set to 'debug' for the FireSass-style output
    fingerprint:
      manifest: '../../assssssets.json'
      targets: ['/js/master.js']
```

In this configuration file, at the bottom, you see `fingerprint`, here you will set what file in config.files you want to hash, because i imagine you don't what to put a hash everywhere !

My problem now is, that i don't know how rename the final file... So how i can do that ? 
 - By renaming the final file ?
 - By duplicating the master.js (generated) and rename it ?

I must do all that in the onCompile function? or teardown (at the end) ?

I have only this doc : github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/plugins.md

I'm confused..

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at the approach of plugin `digest-brunch`: https://github.com/mutewinter/digest-brunch

It uses `onCompile` and lots of code to cover all the edge cases.

That should do the trick.

Comment: HI, his plugin is based on the pattern to replace.
After i don't understand how it rename files... I'm looking for

Comment: If you're asking how to use node to rename a file, take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Comment: Thank you Paul Miller, i have build this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingerprint-brunch Have a good day